# Get input from file and put it in set, Java

Tags: java, file

In my task I need to store class Car into setOfCars. Reading must be done from file. I have id, nameOfCar, noOfSeats.

Input:

> 1
> Mercedes
> GTR 2

In main I have this:

```
Set<Car> listOfCars= eneterCars();
```

But intellij cast it to:

```
 Set<Cars> listOfCars= (Set<Car>) eneterCars();
```

And this doesnt work.

Method I call is also in main:

```
  File cars= new File("dat/cars.txt");

try(FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(cars);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)){
    String readLine;
    List<Car> listOfCars= new ArrayList<>();
    while((readLine= reader.readLine()) != null){
        Long id = Long.parseLong(readLine);
        String name= reader.readLine();
        Integer noOfSeats=Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        listOfCars.add(new Car(id, name, noOfSeats));
        //System.out.println(id + " name" + name+ " " + noOfSeats);
    }

return cars;
```

I want to store information from file to set so that I could use it later. But I get that cast error when I call this function.

Comment: `return cars` actually returns the file not the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written

```
return cars;
```

which is `File cars= new File("dat/cars.txt");`. You need to return the correct object as

```
return listOfCars;
```

Also, instead of declaring `List<Car> listOfCars= new ArrayList<>();` in the method, you could have declared it as `Set<Car> listOfCars= new LinkedHashSet<>();` if you needed a `Set` instead of a `List`.

If you still want to keep the declaration as it is, an idiomatic way to convert it to `Set` is as follows:

```
Set<Cars> listOfCars= new LinkedHashSet<>(eneterCars());
```

**Note:** [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) retains the order to insertion. If the order to insertion does not matter for you, you can use `HashSet`.

Comment: Thanks it helped !

Comment: Thanks I did that

Answer (score 1):

```
public final class Car {

    private final int id;
    private final String manufacture;
    private final String model;

    public Car(int id, String manufacture, String model) {
        this.id = id;
        this.manufacture = manufacture;
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof Car))
            return false;
        return id == ((Car)obj).id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

---

```
public static Set<Car> readCarsFromFile(File file) throws IOException {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        Set<Car> cars = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            int id = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
            String manufacture = scan.nextLine();
            String model = scan.nextLine();
            cars.add(new Car(id, manufacture, model));
        }

        return cars;
    }
}
```

---

**cars.txt**

```
1
Mercedes
GTR 2
2
BMW
X5
```

---

**Demo:**

```
Set<Car> cars = readCarsFromFile(new File("dat/cars.txt"));
// 2 cars: Mersedes, BMW
```